# How to automatically run the executable in GDB?

Tags: gdb

I'd like to have `gdb` immediately run the executable, as if I'd typed "run"
(motivation: I dislike typing "run").

One way is to pipe the command to `gdb` like this:

```
$ echo run | gdb myApp
```

But the problem with this approach is that you lose interactivity with `gdb`,
eg. if a breakpoint triggers or `myApp` crashes, `gdb` quits.
This method is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322110/invoke-gdb-to-automatically-pass-arguments-to-the-program-being-debugged).

Looking at the options in `--help`, I don't see a way to do this, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

```
gdb -ex run ./a.out
```

If you need to pass arguments to `a.out`:

```
gdb -ex run --args ./a.out arg1 arg2 ...
```

EDIT:
[Orion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230851/orion-elenzil) says this doesn't work on Mac OSX.

The `-ex` flag has been available since `GDB-6.4` (released in 2005), but OSX uses Apple's fork of GDB, and the latest XCode for Leopard contains `GDB 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-967)`, so you are out of luck.

Building current `GDB-7.0.1` release is one possible solution. Just be sure to read [this](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin).

Comment: thanks for the answer.
that line behaves the same as just "gdb ./a.out" for me tho.

Comment: I just confirmed that you can also pass multiple -ex options on the command line and they'll run in order before transferring gdb input to you.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the program has arguments like:
`./a.out a b`

Comment: since OSX/xcode no longer supports gdb out of the box (lldb is the new gdb), this now seems like the better approach.

Comment: I made a command file and use `gdb -x` on Linux systems. OS X uses **LLVM** and **clang** so check out the debugging capabilities of `lldb`.

Answer (score 25):

I would use a gdb-script:

```
gdb -x your-script
```

where *your-script* contains something like:

```
file a.out
b main
r
```

afterwards you have the normal interactive gdb prompt

**EDIT**:

here is an optimization for the truly lazy:

1. save the script as `.gdbinit` in the `working directory`.
2. Afterwards you simply run gdb as

   `gdb`

... and gdb automatically loads and executes the content of .gdbinit.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer.
that looks like just what i want except i don't get the gdb prompt, i get gdb being suspended and i'm back at the command line as if i'd typed "ctrl-z".  if i "fg", then gdb resumes and the app runs.
this is OS X.

Comment: orion: mmmh - that's surprising to me. Works well with every UNIX flavor I am actually using (Linux, Solaris, AIX). What gdb version you are using?

Comment: i just re-verfied the behaviour of this - still exits me to the command line w/ gdb suspended.GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:52:12 UTC 2011).

Comment: @orionelenzil No idea why, but if you put `fg` after the `r` line, it acts sanely

Comment: The `start` command provides a shortcut for `b` + `r`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2119606/895245

Answer (score 20):

```
(echo r ; cat) | gdb a.out
```

The cat allows you keep typing after gdb breaks.

Comment: whoa, awesome. you have to ctrl-c after exiting gdb to stop the cat, but that's great.

Comment: It looks like you lose some key-control on the gdb instance using this.

Comment: Moreover, questions like `Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])` will automatically assume answer "No".

Answer (score 11):

**`start` command**

This command is another good option:

```
gdb -ex start --args ./a.out arg1 arg2
```

It is like run, but also sets a temporary breakpoint at `main` and stops there.

This temporary breakpoint is deactivated once it is hit.

**`starti`**

There is also a related `starti` which starts the program and stops at the very first instruction instead, see also: [Stopping at the first machine code instruction in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483544/stopping-at-the-first-machine-code-instruction-in-gdb/48588442#48588442)

Great when you are doing some low level stuff.

Answer (score 4):

`gdb -x <(echo run) --args $program $args`