# GDB CallStack Address virtual or physical?

Tags: gdb, virtual, symbols, nm

My gdb `bt` callstack gives function name with function address. Then I did `nm binary`
and generated the function name and address mapping. When I tried to  match  gdb address with `nm` output it did not match. The function address in `(gdb) bt` where too high (looks like physical address).

gdb function address (e.g `0x00007fffe6fc150f`):

```
#9  0x00007fffe6fc150f in read_alias_file (fname=<value optimized out>, fname_len=<value optimized out>) at localealias.c:224
#10 0x00007fffe6fc1a4e in _nl_expand_alias (name=0x7fffffffed04 "en_IN") at localealias.c:189
#11 0x00007fffe6fbb62f in _nl_find_locale (locale_path=0x7fffe70df580 "/usr/lib/locale", locale_path_len=16, category=12, name=0x7fffffffdb90) at findlocale.c:119
#12 0x00007fffe6fbacf6 in *__GI_setlocale (catesagory=12, locale=<value optimized out>) at setlocale.c:303
#13 0x00007ffff17b8686 in
```

but when I did `nm` the address from the binary I got is like this

```
0000000005ddda04 t StubGLBindFragDataLocationIndexed
0000000005ddda3f t StubGLBindFramebuffer
0000000005ddda65 t StubGLBindRenderbuffer
0000000005ddda8b t StubGLBindTexture
0000000005dddab1 t StubGLBlendColor
0000000005dddaef t StubGLBlendFunc
0000000005dddb15 t StubGLBlitFramebuffer
0000000005dddb7e t StubGLBufferData
0000000005dddbbd t StubGLBufferSubData
0000000005dddc00 t StubGLCheckFramebufferStatus
0000000005dddc1e t StubGLClear
0000000005dddc3c t StubGLClearColor
0000000005dddc7a t StubGLClearStencil
0000000005dddc98 t StubGLColorMask
0000000005dddcda t StubGLCompileShader
```

The Machine is 64 bit.

As i know the gdb shows only virtual address. But I dont know why it is coming so high and 
doesnot match with address present nm output

Is the gdb address are virtual address??. `nm` o/p looks like actual virtual address since it starts from 000000000. But then why base address are added automatically?

Note: I tried with sample test.out. that works fine. The `bt` callstack address are virtual address and perfectly matches with `nm a.out` symbols output.

Answer (score 2):

The `0x00007fffe6fc150f` address is coming from a shared library (`libc.so.6` in this case). It *is* the virtual address, but it will *not* match output from `nm /lib/libc.so.6` because the library is loaded at certain *load* address, which varies from execution to execution.

You can find out when `libc.so.6` is loaded by executing `info proc map` GDB command. Once you know the load address for `libc.so.6`, add it to every address in `nm` output, and the result *will* match GDB output.

The reason this worked for a simple `a.out` is that (unlike shared libraries) `a.out` is linked to be loaded at a fixed load address (usually `0x400000` on Linux x86_64), and is not relocated by the dynamic loader.