# GDB is not stopping at the first machine code instruction with break _start or info files Entry point address

Tags: debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

I want to debug an application I don't have symbol files for. I understood that it is necessary to debug on assembly level if I lack the necessary debug information. Since I don't have debug symbols I can't set breakpoints directly on method names, however I still should be able to set a breakpoint on an address.

So I simply tried to set a breakpoint on the entry address, this is what I did:

```
user@MacBookAir$ gdb
(gdb) file someexecutable
(gdb) info file
```

The last command returned the following entry point:
[image]

After having the address, I simply said:

```
(gdb) break *0x0000000100119ec8
(gdb) run
```

Unfortunately the target application launched without breaking at the entry point, so I tried it again but this time I did set breakpoints on a few addresses following the entry point address - without success.

The next attempt was to try the solution by [Igor Skochinsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/422797/igor-skochinsky) which he posted in this question ([Stopping at the first machine code instruction in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483544/stopping-at-the-first-machine-code-instruction-in-gdb)) to set breakpoints with:

```
(gdb) b _start
(gdb) b start
```

But both of these commands resulted in the same error:

> No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Well yeah, apparently I need debug symbols for this to work as well. Then I thought perhaps it just showed an incorrect entry point address, so I verified it with the command:

```
user@MacBookAir$ otool -l someexecutable
```

And received the following output:
[image]

So it appears to be the same entry point as GDB returned. And now I don't know what else I could try. :)
Perhaps you guys have an idea on what else I could try. Any help would be very much appreciated. If something is unclear or if I missed some important information just leave a short comment.

Comment: I do not reproduce in GDB 7.7.1, GCC 4.8 and a hello world: both address and symbol methods work. How exactly was the executable generated? What is the GDB version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in GDB to me. I'm guessing the ASLR relocates the binary to another address but GDB does not move the breakpoint. I'd suggest one of the following:

1. disable ASLR: `set disable-aslr on`
2. set env var `DYLD_NO_PIE=1`
3. remove the `MH_PIE` flag from the executable's header
4. patch the entrypoint to 0xCC. Once it breaks, you can patch it back to the original byte.

Comment: Awesome to see you dropped by to help me with my question! I tried to disable ASLR or to set the env var, as you suggested, but unfortunately these did not work (it still "skips" the breakpoint). For the latter two options I have to do some research as I'm not very familiar with darwin binaries, will give it a shot tomorrow and report back if I make any progress. :)

Comment: Unfortunately none of these solutions worked for me. I'm closing this now, though, since I cancelled working on this project. Thanks anyway.