# how to force gdb to stop right after the start of program execution?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I've tried to set breakpoint on every function that makes any sense but program exit before reaching any of those. Is there a way to make program run in step-by-step mode from the start so I can see what's going on?

I'm trying to debug /usr/bin/id if it's important (we have custom plugin for it and it's misbehaved)

P.S. Start command doesn't work for me here(it should be a comment, but I don't have enough rep for it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stopping at the first machine code instruction in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483544/stopping-at-the-first-machine-code-instruction-in-gdb)

Comment: (GDB 8.1 introduced `starti`, and the linked duplicate explains older tricks that were usable even for PIE executables.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the program entry point address and insert a breakpoint at that address.

One way to do this is to do info files which gives you for example "Entry point: 0x4045a4". Then do "break *0x4045a4". After run-ning program, it will immediately stop.

From here on you can use single stepping instructions (like step or stepi) to proceed.

You did not tell what system you are trying to debug. If code is in read-only memory you may need to use hardware breakpoints (hbreak) if they are supported by that system.

Comment: The `set break` command seems to do something else at least in GDB 7.7.1 - it expects a subcommand rather than an address. Perhaps, you meant `break *0x4045a4`?

Comment: Sure. break not set break. Fixing answer.

Comment: On Fedora 27, this works for Xorg [which is exempted from building as PIE etc](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1543960), but it does not work for most binaries e.g. `gnome-shell`.  "Cannot insert breakpoint 1. Cannot access memory at address 0x2540".  `break _start` will often work though (for C code, and I guess if the dynamic linker doesn't crash first).

Answer (score 6):

Use `starti`. Unlike `start` this stops at the actual first instruction, not at `main()`.

Comment: This is the most useful answer. It works unconditionally for all programs, and it doesn't need any prior knowledge of the entry point address.

Answer (score 5):

Use [start](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html) command

> The ‘start’ command does the equivalent of setting a temporary breakpoint at the beginning of the main procedure and then invoking the ‘run’ command.

e.g.

a program with debug info **main**, and usage like this: ***main arg1 arg2***

```
gdb main
(gdb) start arg1 arg2
```

Comment: This will work only if a program has the _main_ symbol. If you are debugging a piece of assembly that won't work.

Comment: It also doesn't help if you have an issue *before* `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can type `record full` right after `run`ning the program. This will record all instructions and make them possible for replaying/going back.

For main function, you'd need to type this before reaching the breakpoint so you can set an earlier one by `break _start` -> _start is a function always called before the standard main function. (apparently applies only to the gcc compiler or similar)

Then `continue` to main breakpoint and do `reverse-stepi` to go exactly one instruction back

For more info about recording look here: [link](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Process-Record-and-Replay.html#Process-Record-and-Replay)