# GDB step by step from entry point

Tags: gdb, elf

There is something strange with GDB. I am working on a ELF Linux executable.
I am putting a breakpoint on the program entry point. The program crashes before reaching the breakpoint.
I want to run my program step by step from the beginning.
If i type "step" command in GDB, i got an error message because the program is not in run mode.
Can you tell me how i can reach the very first instruction of the program ? I think it is the dynamic loader but i don t know where it is...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to force gdb to stop right after the start of program execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694620/how-to-force-gdb-to-stop-right-after-the-start-of-program-execution)

Comment: No it is not the samething. I think a code is run before

Comment: So if you put a breakpoint on entry point (not main), and do run, it crashes before hitting a breakpoint?

Comment: Yes it crashé before

Answer (score 1):

> I want to run my program step by step from the beginning.

This is exceptionally hard for the debugger to do: execution starts in unrelocated `ld-linux.so.2`, which self-relocates, initializes `libc.so.6`, then any other directly-linked libraries, and finally passes control to the `a.out` entry point.

The fact that the debugger has to deal with both before and after self-relocation addresses is what makes it difficult / confusing.

Fortunately, it is also not usually necessary, even for `ld-linux` developers. You should probably abandon the idea that you will be able to step through `ld-linux` execution, and figure out how to debug whatever problem you actually have by other means (including asking for help with your *actual* problem here).

Comment: I think this is the OS that do something with ld-linux in order to load libraries. Maybe i do not have the good library, i will look in this direction thanks