# Why cant i set Breakpoints using the memory addresses

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compilation, x86-64

I am learning Assembly Processor architecture and exploit development when I came across this tutorial for x68_64 bufferOverFlows, so i copied the vuln code and compiled it using gcc. My compiled binary does not let me set breakpoints but when i downloaded the binary from the website("I did not want to do this ") it worked fine and memory address were normal

But when i dump main in my compiled program with gdb my memory addresses look like this:
    0x000000000000085e <+83>:   lea    -0xd0(%rbp),%rax

```
End of assembler dump.
```

When i try to set a Break poing after the scanf function:
    (gdb) break *0x000000000000085e
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x85e
    (gdb) run

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void validate(char *pass) {
   if (strcmp(pass, "[REDACTED]") == 0) {
        printf("ACCESS GRANTED!");
        printf("Oh that's just idio... Oh my god!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Damn it, I had something for this...\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char password[200];
    printf("C:/ENTER PASSWORD: ");
    scanf("%s", password);
    validate(password);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", password);`,  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current scenario, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  2) when using the input format specifier '%s' and/or '%[...]', always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer, to avoid buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.  Suggest: `if( 1 != scanf("%199s", password) ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for password failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );  }`

Comment: when the parameters to the function: `main()` are not going to be used, then suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: Okay thanks,  This program is supposed to be vulnerable though and im just a beginner. basically i copy and pasted this then compiled it using gcc and my memory addresses come out weird i dont know where to begin to look for this answer or word it my memory addresses look as so 0x6c5 weird missing a digit.

Comment: also when i donwloaded the program from the tutorial website and checked the addresses his came out to look as so 0x6a84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set breakpoints on virtual addresses, but `objdump` doesn't know where your PIE executable will be mapped into memory, so it uses `0` as a base address.  To make things simpler, disable PIE ([which your distro apparently enables by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)).  Presumably your tutorial was written before this was common.  **Use `gcc -fno-pie -no-pie -g foo.c -o foo`**.  Then addresses you see in `objdump -drwC -Mintel` will match run-time addresses.

But IDK why you want numeric addresses; use `b main` and single-step from there.  Even if you leave out `-g`, you'll still have symbol names for functions.

---

To solve the question as asked, see [Stopping at the first machine code instruction in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483544/stopping-at-the-first-machine-code-instruction-in-gdb/43722241#43722241) and [Set a breakpoint on GDB entry point for stripped PIE binaries without disabling ASLR](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/set-a-breakpoint-on-gdb-entry-point-for-stripped-pie-binaries-without-disabling/8748#8748).

Once you have a running process from your executable, you can `p &main` or `disas main` to find the actual runtime address of `main`.  But note that gdb disables ASLR, so if you use code addresses you find with GDB in your exploit against a PIE executable, they will *only* work when run under GDB.  Running it "normally" will randomize the virtual address where your executable is mapped.  (This is why I suggested building a position-dependent executable).  But more likely you just want to return to executable code on an executable stack, in which case it's stack ASLR that matters, and stack-ASLR still happens in plain old position-dependent executables (unless you disable it too, like gdb does).

Comment: Thanks  this sounds reliable Ill try it out.

Comment: Works 100%   0x0000000000400792