# GDB put breakpoint at very first instruction

Tags: gdb

When i type:

```
gdb mybinary
```

mybinary is a PIE executatable (Position indépendant Code).

i get a gdb prompt. The binary is not fully loaded in memory. Why do i say that ? This is because we do not know at this step what is the address of main entry point.

It is sometimes possible to type disassemble main, but i my case, the binary do not contains debugging informations.

If a type "run", the loader loads the program in memory and the program runs.

What should i do to force gdb to just run the loader and break on the first instruction in main. Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping at the first machine code instruction in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483544/stopping-at-the-first-machine-code-instruction-in-gdb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible

Sure. Here is one way to do it:

```
$ echo "int main() { return 0; }" | gcc -xc -
$ gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) x/i &main
   0x5fa <main>:    push   %rbp
```

Note that this is a PIE binary, and it has not been relocated yet (no code will ever execute at address `0x5fa` on a Linux system).

```
(gdb) set stop-on-solib-events 1
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
(gdb) x/i &main
   0x5555555545fa <main>:   push   %rbp
```

You can now see that the binary has been relocated, and can set a breakpoint on `main`.

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x5555555545fe
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x00005555555545fe in main ()
```

Voilà.

Comment: @Bob5421  Code that performs dynamic relocations is in the dynamic loader: `ld-linux.so.2`.

Answer (score 1):

In modern GDB, `start` sets a temporary breakpoint in `main` (after ASLR) and runs.  That command was added in the past couple years, and certainly streamlines things.

Setting a breakpoint on `main` does also work (at least in recent GDB) even in a PIE executable where `main`'s true address not known until after `run`.  This depends on `main` existing in the symbol table, but so does `start`.

`b main` before `run` shows it being set at address `0x111d` for example, but then after `run` it's hit at address `0x000055555555511d`.  Modern GDB apparently knows that ASLR will happen and updates breakpoints that you set symbolically, not via `b *0x111d`

---

If there isn't even a `main` symbol:

You can only use **`starti` to stop before running any user-space instructions at all**, like your question title indicates.

Or perhaps @Employed Russian's suggestion of `set stop-on-solib-events 1` can help you stop somewhere somewhat interesting even in a stripped binary.

Comment: `starti` is just perfect!