# GDB - breakpoint pending on future shared library load

Tags: assembly, gdb

I'm trying to run a very simple linked file in GDB.

I did the following actions:

```
(gdb) break _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000b0
(gdb) start
Function "main" not defined.
**Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) ?**
```

However the label *_start* isn't in any shared library, but simply in the assembly code that generated the executable. Why does GDB ask this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GDB `start` command sets a breakpoint at the start of `main`, and then runs your program.  Presumably your program doesn't have a `main` symbol.

Read the error message carefully, it says `Function "main" not defined.`  The breakpoint at `_start` is already set; if that was the problem you'd have seen the prompt after *that* command, and wouldn't have seen a numeric address.  (Try it with `b  xyz` or `b printf`.)

---

**You're looking for the `run` command, which *just* runs the program without looking for any symbols in it.**

Use `help start` and `help run` in GDB to see what they do.

Or the online docs: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html

- `run`: just start the program, no new breakpoints added.
- `start`: set a one-time breakpoint in `main` before `run`.  Useful for compiled C/C++, or hand-written asm that defines a `main` and uses the standard CRT startup files.  This is what you tried to use.
- **`starti`: stop at the first asm instruction of the process**.  Especially useful for a PIE executable without symbols, where the entry-point numeric address isn't known until after ASLR chooses it, if you run it with ASLR enabled.  (The GDB default behaviour is to disable ASLR).

`starti` is a relatively recent feature; before that one common hack was to use `b *0`, which leads to an error right after the process starts, before any instructions execute.  [Stopping at the first machine code instruction in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483544/stopping-at-the-first-machine-code-instruction-in-gdb/43722241#43722241)

Comment: (I'm sorry if i ask this, but the online resources for Assembly seem very few) Let's suppose that after typing "start" i made a breakpoint pending on future shared library load. If i load a shared library, when does the compiler go to check if the main label is present ? Does the library get simply copy-pasted at the beginning of the source file that loaded it ?

Comment: @Koinos: This isn't an assembly issue, it's a shared-library / linking issue. 
But anyway, the compiler isn't doing any checking of anything when you're debugging with GDB.  If your executable itself didn't contain a `main` function, but was linked against a shared library that did, then it would make sense.  `main` is not a normal use-case for this, but it's the same GDB prompt as for setting breakpoints on other functions, like `printf`.