# How can I debug functions in shared object libraries with GDB?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to verify the functionality of functions in a shared object library. In programs with a `main` function, I would simply `start` the program and gdb would automatically breakpoint on main, but that's obviously not available here.

Let's say I have some `add.c`:

```
long add(long x, long y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

I compile this with `gcc -shared -o libadd.so -fPIC add.c` and load it into GDB:

```
(gdb) file libadd.so
Reading symbols from libadd.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) start
Function "main" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
Starting program: /tmp/minimal/libadd.so

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
```

Preferably, I would like to be able to use gdb similar to below:

```
(gdb) file libadd.so
Reading symbols from libadd.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) call (long)add(5,6)
$1 = 11
```

But this call results in `You can't do that without a process to debug`.

Can I debug libraries like this in GDB?

Comment: Nice canonical question. +1 for both.

Comment: @JL2210 Took me a solid 3 or 4 hours to figure this out yesterday. Figured it might be useful in the future for someone else since this strikes me as something that would be a fairly common problem.

Comment: You should accept your own answer now to make this question look as answered in the list of questions.

Answer (score 6):

You can do so with `starti`, as shown below:

```
(gdb) file libadd.so
Reading symbols from libadd.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) starti
Starting program /tmp/minimal/libadd.so

Program stopped.
0x00007ffff7dfd4a0 in deregister_tm_clones ()
(gdb) call (long)add(5,6)
$1 = 11
```

You can also do this with binaries containing a main function, as seen in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483544/stopping-at-the-first-machine-code-instruction-in-gdb).

Comment: Undefined command: "starti".  Try "help".

Comment: Starting with GDB 8.1

Comment: For some reason, I find that this segfaults when I call the function....

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this is by creating a dummy executable that links the shared library:

```c
#include "thelib.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc == 100000) {
        // Call any function from the library, so that the shared library will be used
        sub(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Then, compile and debug this executable, linking to the shared library:

```sh
$ gdb dummy
(gdb) start
(gdb) call (long)add(5, 6)
```