# How can I debug functions in shared object libraries with GDB in MINGW64?

Tags: c, gdb, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm trying to reconstruct [How can I debug functions in shared object libraries with GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690952/how-can-i-debug-functions-in-shared-object-libraries-with-gdb) answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59690953/6197439 in MINGW64 gdb - and I cannot:

```
$ cat add.c
long add(long x, long y) {
    return x + y;
}

$ gcc -shared -o libadd.so -fPIC add.c

$ gdb
GNU gdb (GDB) 13.2
...

(gdb) file libadd.so
Reading symbols from libadd.so...

(gdb) starti
Starting program: C:\msys64\tmp\libadd.so
Error creating process C:\msys64\tmp\libadd.so, (error 193: unknown win32 error (193))
```

So, how would I go about calling a function in MINGW64 `gdb`, in an .so file like this one, compiled with MINGW64 `gcc`?

Comment: Why `.so` rather than `.dll`? Not sure if it matters. Or perhaps this trick doesn't work on Windows in the first place, and you need a `main()`.

Comment: You need to compile with -g and possibly -ggdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MINGW64 gdb - and I cannot:

Your problem is *not* that you can't set a breakpoint; your problem is that you are trying to *run* a `.so` file.

You need an actual *executable* (which either depends on your `.so` or loads it dynamically).

The [upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59690953/50617) is *wrong*. The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67248434/50617) is correct.

Comment: Thanks a ton - that was it; I went over to having an exe, and it worked.